# Pseudo header fields for IPV6 packets

Tags: c, network-programming, ipv6

I am working on calculating checksum values for IPV6 packets.

How to calculate the values for destination address and length field for pseudo address in case of extension headers ?

Answer (score 2):

[RFC 2460 section 8.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2460.html#section-8.1) specifies all this. Some highlights:

When determining the pseudo-header destination address when extension headers that change the destination address are used you use the destination address that the recipient would see:

> If the IPv6 packet contains a Routing header, the Destination Address
> used in the pseudo-header is that of the final destination.  At the
> originating node, that address will be in the last element of the
> Routing header; at the recipient(s), that address will be in the
> Destination Address field of the IPv6 header.

When determining the upper layer packet length you don't count any extension headers, only the final (upper layer) header and its data:

> The Upper-Layer Packet Length in the pseudo-header is the length of
> the upper-layer header and data (e.g., TCP header plus TCP data).
> Some upper-layer protocols carry their own length information (e.g.,
> the Length field in the UDP header); for such protocols, that is the
> length used in the pseudo-header.  Other protocols (such as TCP) do
> not carry their own length information, in which case the length used
> in the pseudo-header is the Payload Length from the IPv6 header, minus
> the length of any extension headers present between the IPv6 header
> and the upper-layer header.